# How to display full text of a dataField in TableHeaderColumn in BootStrapTable

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I want to display text in column of a table but text is too big to fit in column, my code is as below.

```
<TableHeaderColumn width="100%" dataField="description">Description</TableHeaderColumn>
```

I read different articles and came to conclusion tht column title can help me so I tried to use columnTtitle as below.

```
<TableHeaderColumn width="100%" columnTtitle ="description">Description</TableHeaderColumn>
```

now when hover on cell it display *description* and does not shows the text stored in description.

I am new to bootstrap so pardon if my question sounds stupid, but I need help, thanks in advance.

Sara

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to show the whole text as follow, I added columnTitle={true} and it worked

```
<TableHeaderColumn width="100%" dataField="description" columnTitle={true}>Description</TableHeaderColumn>
```